# How to perform non-fresh logins using Devise/Rspec/Capybara/Poltergeist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

While performing integration/system tests with rspec/capybara/poltergeist, I am trying to test non-fresh logins using Devise.

```
before(:each) do
      login_as(user, :scope => :spree_user)
      user.current_sign_in_at = 1.day.ago
      user.save!
    end

    it "should prompt me for my password" do
      visit "/"
      expect(page).to have_content("Welcome back, #{user.email}. Enter your password to continue.")
    end
```

I can verify that the user object successfully updates the `current_sign_in_at` date, however when the root page is rendered, the user's `current_sign_in_at` timestamp gets updated to today's date.

How can I keep the value consistent after a next request?

I am expecting the user's `current_sign_in_at` to be Today's date minus 1 day, however I am consistently receiving today's date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `login_as` is from Warden::Test::Helpers, it works by setting up a hook for the next request which logs the user in.  That means the actual 'logging in' doesn't actually occur until the `visit "/"` call which will overwrite the value you've saved. I haven't tried this, but it should be possible to set `devise.skip_trackable` in the request environment by registering your own request hook rather than calling login_as and thereby stop the login dates from being updated

```
Warden.on_next_request do |proxy|
  opts[:event] ||= :authentication
  proxy.env['devise.skip_trackable'] = true
  proxy.set_user(user, opts)
end
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. That did the job. I just wrapped that within my own helper.